# Creating a Link inside a Symfony generated Excel

Tags: symfony

Hello Symfony developers,
I'm using [Stats-Table-Bundle](https://github.com/igraal/stats-table-bundle) to generate an Excel sheet from the Database.

I'm interested to give the columns a better formating. But also I would like to insert some Edit links pointing to the CMS.

Did anyone tried to make this with a Stats-Table-Bundle generated excel ? Or with any other Symfony component ?

I would like to see an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating desktop documents is not in the focus of Symfony. But there are several 3rd party libraries, like PHPexcel, which you can easily install and manage through composer.

For example, if you want to use PHPexcel, simply add `phpoffice/phpexcel` to your `composer.json` and run `composer update`:

```
…
"require" : {
    …
    "phpoffice/phpexcel" : "~1.8"
}
…
```

This will install the PHPexcel package as part of your symfony installation.

Then, wherever you need it, create an instance of PHPexcel and use it [according to the docs](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/03-Creating-a-Spreadsheet.md):

```
$phpExcel = new \PHPExcel();
```

For the other aspect of your question, regarding the hyperlink:

In the PHPexcel docs, there's a [section about “making a cell clickable”](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#change-a-cell-into-a-clickable-url) with the following example:

```
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E26', 'www.phpexcel.net');
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E26')->getHyperlink()->setUrl('http://www.phpexcel.net');
```